# How can I remove non numeric values for colMeans() function in R?

Tags: r

This is the line,

```
colMeans3 <- colMeans(grade3, na.rm=TRUE)
```

and R says

```
Error in colMeans(grades3, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 3):

Subset `grade3` to include only numeric variables.

```
grade3 <- data.frame(a = runif(10), b = rnorm(10), c = letters[1:10])
colMeans(grade3)

find.numeric <- sapply(grade3, is.numeric)
colMeans(grade3[, find.numeric])
        a         b 
0.4675017 0.1642704
```

Comment: what if one of the values in the data set is <NA>?
the column with <NA> as a value was not included in the result.

Comment: `<NA>` indicates you have factors in your data set. If you believe they are numeric, you can convert them to using `as.numeric(as.character(x))`, otherwise you have to exclude them from `colMeans` function.